# Clarification in a proof that $n!\leq n^n$

Tags: inequality, induction, proof-explanation, factorial

Can someone explain me,I am not able to understand last line (underlined)[image]

Comment: The last line uses the induction hypothesis i.e. $n!\leq n^n$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260233/inductive-proof-that-kkk-for-k-geq-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$ is valid by definition.
2. $(n+1)n! \le (n+1)n^n$ comes from the induction hypothesis.
3. From $n<n+1$ we get $n^n <(n+1)^n$ and therefore $(n+1)n^n<(n+1)^{n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

By definition $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$.

By hypothesis, $n!\le n^n$ and so $(n+1)n!\le (n+1)n^n$.

Then, since $n<(n+1)$, $n^n<(n+1)^n$ and so $(n+1)n^n<(n+1)(n+1)^n=(n+1)^{n+1}$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark